# my delete function is not printing anything

Tags: c, red-black-tree

I have this code of a red-black tree in which it has the functions mainly of insertion and deletion.

But when trying to perform the deleteNode function, it does not display anything in the output.

being that if I use only the insertion and printing on the screen, the code runs normally.

I believe that the logic is right but I'm doing some manipulation with the struct that is generating the problem.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#define BLACK 0
#define RED 1

struct RBNo
{

    int data;
    int cor;
    struct RBNo *esq;
    struct RBNo *dir;
    struct RBNo *pai;
};

struct RBNo *Novo_no_vermelho(int data, struct RBNo *pai){
    struct RBNo *novoNO = (struct RBNo *)malloc(sizeof(struct RBNo));
    novoNO->pai = pai;
    novoNO->esq = novoNO->dir = NULL;
    novoNO->cor = RED;
    novoNO->data = data;
    return novoNO;
}

struct RBNo *Novo_no_preto(int data){
    struct RBNo *RBNo = (struct RBNo *)malloc(sizeof(struct RBNo));
    RBNo->pai = RBNo->esq = RBNo->dir = NULL;
    RBNo->cor = BLACK;
    RBNo->data = data;
    return RBNo;
}

int filho_esquerda(struct RBNo *raiz){
    struct RBNo *pai = raiz->pai;
    return (pai->esq == raiz);
}

struct RBNo *Encontrar_irmao(struct RBNo *raiz){
    struct RBNo *pai = raiz->pai;
    return (filho_esquerda(raiz) ? pai->dir : pai->esq);
}

void RR(struct RBNo *raiz, int mudar_cor){
    struct RBNo *pai = raiz->pai;
    raiz->pai = pai->pai;
    if (pai->pai != NULL){
        if(pai->pai->dir == pai)
            pai->pai->dir = raiz;

        else
            pai->pai->esq = raiz;
    }
    struct RBNo *dir = raiz->dir;
    raiz->dir = pai;
    pai->pai = raiz;
    pai->esq = dir;
    if (dir != NULL)
        dir->pai = pai;
    if (mudar_cor){
        raiz->cor = BLACK;
        pai->cor = RED;
    }
}

void LL(struct RBNo *raiz, int mudar_cor){
    struct RBNo *pai = raiz->pai;
    raiz->pai = pai->pai;
    if (pai->pai != NULL){
        if (pai->pai->dir == pai)
            pai->pai->dir = raiz;
        else
            pai->pai->esq = raiz;
    }

    struct RBNo *esq = raiz->esq;

    raiz->esq = pai;
    pai->pai = raiz;
    pai->dir = esq;

    if (esq != NULL)
        esq->pai = pai;

    if (mudar_cor){
        raiz->cor = BLACK;
        pai->cor = RED;
    }
}

struct RBNo *Insercao(struct RBNo *pai, struct RBNo *raiz, int data){
    if (raiz == NULL){
        if (pai != NULL)
            return Novo_no_vermelho(data, pai);
        return Novo_no_preto(data);
    }
    int na_esquerda;
    if (raiz->data > data){
        struct RBNo *esq = Insercao(raiz, raiz->esq, data);
        if (esq == raiz->pai)
            return esq;
        raiz->esq = esq;
        na_esquerda = 1;
    }
    else if (raiz->data < data){
        struct RBNo *dir = Insercao(raiz, raiz->dir, data);
        if (dir == raiz->pai)
            return dir;
        raiz->dir = dir;
        na_esquerda = 0;
    }
    else
        return raiz;
    if (na_esquerda){
        if (raiz->cor == RED && raiz->esq->cor == RED){
            struct RBNo *sibling = Encontrar_irmao(raiz);
            if (!sibling || sibling->cor == BLACK){
                if (filho_esquerda(raiz))
                    RR(raiz, 1);
                else{
                    RR(raiz->esq, 0);
                    raiz = raiz->pai;
                    LL(raiz, 1);
                }
            }
            else{
                raiz->cor = BLACK;
                sibling->cor = BLACK;
                if (raiz->pai->pai != NULL)
                    raiz->pai->cor = RED;
            }
        }
    }
    else{
        if (raiz->cor == RED && raiz->dir->cor == RED){
            struct RBNo *sibling = Encontrar_irmao(raiz);
            if (!sibling || sibling->cor == BLACK){
                if (!filho_esquerda(raiz))
                    LL(raiz, 1);
                else{
                    LL(raiz->dir, 0);
                    raiz = raiz->pai;
                    RR(raiz, 1);
                }
            }
            else{
                raiz->cor = BLACK;
                sibling->cor = BLACK;
                if (raiz->pai->pai != NULL)
                    raiz->pai->cor = RED;
            }
        }
    }
    return raiz;
}





void deleteFix(struct RBNo* x, struct RBNo* node)
  {
    struct RBNo* s;
    while (x != node && x->cor == 0){
      if (x == x->pai->esq){
        s = x->pai->dir;
        if (s->cor == 1){
          s->cor = 0;
          x->pai->cor = 1;
          LL(x->pai, 1);
          s = x->pai->dir;
        }

        if (s->esq->cor == 0 && s->dir->cor == 0)
        {
          s->cor = 1;
          x = x->pai;
        }
        else
        {
          if (s->dir->cor == 0)
          {
            s->esq->cor = 0;
            s->cor = 1;
            RR(s, 0);
            s = x->pai->dir;
          }

          s->cor = x->pai->cor;
          x->pai->cor = 0;
          s->dir->cor = 0;
          LL(x->pai, 0);
          x = node;
        }
      }
      else
      {
        s = x->pai->esq;
        if (s->cor == 1)
        {
          s->cor = 0;
          x->pai->cor = 1;
          RR(x->pai, 0);
          s = x->pai->esq;
        }

        if (s->dir->cor == 0 && s->dir->cor == 0)
        {
          s->cor = 1;
          x = x->pai;
        }
        else
        {
          if (s->esq->cor == 0)
          {
            s->dir->cor = 0;
            s->cor = 1;
            LL(s, 0);
            s = x->pai->esq;
          }

          s->cor = x->pai->cor;
          x->pai->cor = 0;
          s->esq->cor = 0;
          RR(x->pai, 0);
          x = node;
        }
      }
    }
    x->cor = 0;
  }

  struct RBNo* minimum(struct RBNo* node)
  {
    while (node->esq != NULL)
    {
      node = node->esq;
    }
    return node;
  }

void rbTransplant(struct RBNo* raiz , struct RBNo* u, struct RBNo* v){
    if (u->pai == NULL){
      raiz = v;
    }
    else if (u == u->pai->esq)
    {
      u->pai->esq = v;
    }
    else
    {
      u->pai->dir = v;
    }
    v->pai = u->pai;
  }

void deleteNode(struct RBNo* node){

    struct RBNo* z = NULL;
    struct RBNo* x;
    struct RBNo* y;

    while (node != NULL){
        z = node;
        node = node->esq;
    }

    y = z;
    int y_original_cor = y->cor;
    if (z->esq == NULL){
      x = z->dir;
      rbTransplant(node, z, z->dir);
    }
    else if (z->dir == NULL){
      x = z->esq;
      rbTransplant(node, z, z->esq);
    }
    else{
      y = minimum(z->dir);
      y_original_cor = y->cor;
      x = y->dir;
      if (y->pai == z){
        x->pai = y;
      }
      else{
        rbTransplant(node, y, y->dir);
        y->dir = z->dir;
        y->dir->pai = y;
      }
      rbTransplant(node, z, y);
      y->esq = z->esq;
      y->esq->pai = y;
      y->cor = z->cor;
    }
    free(z);
    if (y_original_cor == 0)
    {
      deleteFix(x, node);
    }
  }







void Impressao(struct RBNo *raiz, bool ultimo){
    if (raiz != NULL){
        printf(" ");
        if (raiz->cor == 0)
            printf("%d BLACK\n", raiz->data);
        else
            printf("%d RED\n", raiz->data);
        Impressao(raiz->esq, false);
        Impressao(raiz->dir, true);
    }
}

int main()
{

    struct RBNo *raiz = NULL;

    raiz = Insercao(NULL, raiz, 41);
    raiz = Insercao(NULL, raiz, 17);
    raiz = Insercao(NULL, raiz, 34);
    raiz = Insercao(NULL, raiz, 43);
    deleteNode(raiz);
    raiz = Insercao(NULL, raiz, 24);
    raiz = Insercao(NULL, raiz, 25);
    raiz = Insercao(NULL, raiz, 49);
    raiz = Insercao(NULL, raiz, 32);
    raiz = Insercao(NULL, raiz, 36);

    Impressao(raiz, true);
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

That is, the only thing I need is to find out why the code does not display anything when I use the `deleteNode` function and what is wrong with it, because I'm almost sure that the logic is right.

Comment: Welcome so SO. Does your function print properly before using `deleteNode`? Does it print properly immediately afterwards? Did yo run your program in a debugger and inspect your data structures are handled correctly? That should be the first step in hunting for errors.

Comment: `free(z);` This frees the passed `node`, i.e. `raiz` but the caller does not see it. After calling `deleteNode` `raiz` is invalid.

Comment: If you pass `NULL` to `deleteNode` you will access it without any check: `if (z->esq == NULL)` causing undefined behaviour.

Comment: "the logic is right but I'm doing some manipulation with the struct that is generating the problem." Which basically means, the logic is not right.

Comment: So, basically this code is on a red-black binary tree in which it mainly performs 2 functions, the insercao and the deleteNode

when I use only insertion, the code works normally, printing on the screen what really should be shown

however when I use the deleteNode function, which has the function of deleting a specific node from the tree

nothing is displayed in the output, so I think it must be some mistake that I'm making in the manipulation of the structure inside the deleteNode function or any of the functions inside it

Comment: See my second comment. You mess up your `raiz` pointer. Why doesn't `deleteNode` function return the modified pointer as the other functions do?

Comment: I understand, I will try to modify here then

is that I took this function from a code in c ++ and tried to adapt it, so I thought I was just sending the root of main to this function and it would be modified

Comment: but following your line of thought, why do my functions like LL and RR that do not return anything manage to modify the raiz?

Comment: What do you mean? `LL` and `RR` do not modify `raiz` at all. Modifying `raiz` and modifying `raiz->something` is very different.